# C OpenMPI, add rows to dynamically allocated local matrices

Tags: c, image-processing, mpi, openmpi, scatter

For this college task I need to parallelize an image processing program. I've almost solved the problem, but I struggled when comes to row distribution.

My steps so far are:

1. Load binary data into a matrix at process 1
2. Add padding to the matrix
3. Scatterv the data between all processes using a MPI_DataType and send them to local matrices

And now I should convolute them, gatherv the data and store it in a file. But I need to add some rows.

So this is the content of the local matrices (one to one respectively of num processes):

[image: Local matrices]

As you can see:

- process 0 needs to get the first row from process 1 local matrix and append it
- process 1 needs to append the first row from process 2 and push the last row from process 0
- same for process 2 but swapping 0 to 1 and 2 to 3
- push process 2 last row

Here is the code (Spanish comments):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Archivos input/output
    const char *input_file = "datos.raw", *output_file = "output.raw";

    // Matriz de datos y imagen resultado
    unsigned char **matrix, **result;

    // Atributos de las imágenes
    int width = 20, height = 20;

    // Parámetros MPI
    int nprocess;
    int myrank;
    int root = 0;

    // Inicio MPI
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocess);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

    // Parámetros para las matrices con padding
    int pad_batch;         // Filas por procesos
    int pad_bigger_batch;  // Cantidad de Procesos que tendran una fila más
    int *pad_send_from;    // Índices de filas iniciales
    int *pad_size_to_send; // Desplazamiento desde filas iniciales (offset)

    // Parámetros para las matrices convulsionadas
    int res_batch;
    int res_bigger_batch;
    int *res_send_from;
    int *res_size_to_send;

    // Tipos de datos personalizados para utilizar con scatterv y gatherv
    MPI_Datatype pad_row_type; // Tipo de dato para matrices con padding
    MPI_Type_contiguous(width + 2, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, &pad_row_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&pad_row_type);

    MPI_Datatype row_type;  // Tipo de dato para matrices resultantes
    MPI_Type_contiguous(width, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, &row_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&row_type);

    // Carga de datos en root
    if (myrank == root)
    {
        matrix = allocate_matrix(width + 2, height + 2);
        result = allocate_matrix(width, height);
        read_binary_data(matrix, input_file, width, height);
        padding(matrix, width, height);
    }

    // Inicio distribución de los datos

    pad_batch = (height + 2) / nprocess;
    pad_bigger_batch = (height + 2) % nprocess;

    pad_send_from = malloc((height + 2) * sizeof(int));
    pad_size_to_send = malloc((height + 2) * sizeof(int));

    calc_index_offset(pad_send_from, pad_size_to_send, pad_batch, pad_bigger_batch, height + 2);

    // Matrices locales para cada proceso
    unsigned char **local_matrix = allocate_local_matrix(width + 2, pad_size_to_send[myrank]);

    if (myrank == root)
    {
        MPI_Scatterv(&matrix[0][0], pad_size_to_send, pad_send_from, pad_row_type, &local_matrix[0][0], pad_size_to_send[myrank], pad_row_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Scatterv(NULL, pad_size_to_send, pad_send_from, pad_row_type, &local_matrix[0][0], pad_size_to_send[myrank], pad_row_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    // Fin Inicio distribución de los datos

    // Inicio carga de datos en matrices locales y parámetros necesarios para los resultados locales
    res_batch = (height) / nprocess;
    res_bigger_batch = (height) % nprocess;

    res_size_to_send = malloc((height) * sizeof(int));
    res_send_from = malloc((height) * sizeof(int));

    // Se recalculan los índices iniciales y el desplazamiento
    calc_index_offset(res_send_from, res_size_to_send, res_batch, res_bigger_batch, height);

    // Se almacena memoria para los resultados locales
    unsigned char **local_result = allocate_local_matrix(width, res_size_to_send[myrank]);

    // Print local_matrix
    printf("proces %d\n", myrank);
    for (int i = 0; i < pad_size_to_send[myrank]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width + 2; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d", local_matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

   // TODO?
}
```

How matrices are stored:

```
unsigned char **allocate_matrix(int width, int height)
{
    unsigned char **matrix, *data;
    matrix = (unsigned char **)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char *) * height);
    data = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * height * sizeof(unsigned char));
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = &(data[i * width]);
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

How Offset/Displs/Size is calculated:

```
void calc_index_offset(int *send_from, int *size_to_send, int batch, int bigger_batch, int height)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        send_from[i] = (i == 0) ? 0 : send_from[i - 1] + size_to_send[i - 1];
        size_to_send[i] = (i < bigger_batch) ? (batch + 1) : batch;
    }
}
```

Comment: tag these questions `mpi` since they are not specific to the OpenMPI implementation. you'll get 5x more eyes.

Comment: You don't have a matrix: you have an array of pointers to arrays. Create your matrix contiguously. (I swear I've seen your code before and that I've told you this before. Do you keep deleting questions and reposting?)

Comment: Actually is a contiguous block pointed by matrix and it works @VictorEijkhout And this won't work on a static matrix because it's size